# how to get work with dynamically inserted fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the below div class 'labouritems' which gets a new instance of it inserted into the dom each time the user clicks on a button.

I need to be able to calculate the '.rate' and '.hours' fields and set the answer to the '.total' field.

Now this is for only the instance of 'labouritems' that the user is working on, ie: should not update the field total on another instance' so basically just work within that row.

Below is the html that i'm working with and below that is the code i have which only works for the first instance of 'labouritems' but when i insert a new one it does not do anything.

```
 <div class="labouritems">
        <label for="quote_labouritems_attributes_0_description">Description</label>
        <input class="input-medium" id="quote_labouritems_attributes_0_description" name="quote[labouritems_attributes][0][description]" size="30" type="text" value="concrete the house">
        <label for="quote_labouritems_attributes_0_hours">Hours</label>
        <input class="input-mini hours" id="quote_labouritems_attributes_0_hours" name="quote[labouritems_attributes][0][hours]" size="30" type="text" value="33">
        <label for="quote_labouritems_attributes_0_total">Total</label>
        <input class="input-mini total" id="quote_labouritems_attributes_0_total" name="quote[labouritems_attributes][0][total]" size="30" type="text" value="1089">
        <label for="quote_labouritems_attributes_0_Mup/Hr">Mup/hr</label>
        <input class="input-mini" id="quote_labouritems_attributes_0_muphourrate" name="quote[labouritems_attributes][0][muphourrate]" size="30" type="text" value="0">
          <label for="quote_labouritems_attributes_0_Mup/Total">Mup/total</label>
        <input class="input-mini" id="quote_labouritems_attributes_0_muptotal" name="quote[labouritems_attributes][0][muptotal]" size="30" type="text" value="0">
        <label for="quote_labouritems_attributes_0_Mup/%">Mup/%</label>
        <input class="input-mini" id="quote_labouritems_attributes_0_muppercent" name="quote[labouritems_attributes][0][muppercent]" size="30" type="text">
        <label for="quote_labouritems_attributes_0_Contractor">Contractor</label>

        <input class="input-small" data-autocomplete="/contractors/autocomplete_contractor_firstname" data-update-elements="{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;#quote_labouritems_attributes_0_contractor_id&quot;,&quot;hourly_rate&quot;:&quot;#quote_labouritems_attributes_0_contractor_rate&quot;}" id="quote_labouritems_attributes_0_contractor_name" name="quote[labouritems_attributes][0][contractor_name]" placeholder="Seach" size="30" type="text" value="bing lee">
        <input id="quote_labouritems_attributes_0_contractor_id" name="quote[labouritems_attributes][0][contractor_id]" type="hidden" value="1">
        <label for="quote_labouritems_attributes_0_Rate/hr">Rate/hr</label>
        <input class="input-mini rate" id="quote_labouritems_attributes_0_contractor_rate" name="quote[labouritems_attributes][0][contractor_rate]" size="30" type="text" value="33">
        <label for="quote_labouritems_attributes_0_Work %">Work %</label>
        <input class="input-mini" id="quote_labouritems_attributes_0_progress_percent" name="quote[labouritems_attributes][0][progress_percent]" size="30" type="text" value="55">
        <label for="quote_labouritems_attributes_0_Work $">Work $</label>
        <input class="input-mini" id="quote_labouritems_attributes_0_progress_payment" name="quote[labouritems_attributes][0][progress_payment]" size="30" type="text">

        <input id="quote_labouritems_attributes_0__destroy" name="quote[labouritems_attributes][0][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="false"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-small btn-danger remove_nested_fields" data-association="labouritems">Delete</a>
    </div>​




 var LabourItems = {
   rate: null,
   hours: null,
   total: null,
   init: function(object) {
      this.rate = parseInt($(object).children('.rate').first().val(), 10);
      // var rate = $(object).children('.rate').first();
      this.hours =parseInt($(object).children('.hours').first().val(), 10);
      this.total = this.rate * this.hours;
      this.updateTotal(object);
   },
   updateTotal: function(object) {
      $(object).children('.total').first().val(this.total || 0);
   }
}

//reactTochange for those inputs that you want to observe
$('.hours').on("keyup", function() {
   $('.labouritems').each( function(key,value){
      LabourItems.init(this);
   });
});
```

Comment: you already asked this question and you got a proper answer. you don't have to ask for each small peace of your code. you are the developer...so you should do your code.

Comment: dude if i would have gotten the right answer i wouldn't have to keep asking, this site is all about scores and just write up a quick answer, there is no follow on for any questions.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(documents).on("keyup", '.hours', function() {
    LabourItems.init(this.closest('.labouritems'));
});
```

this will
1. attach hours.keyup event on document, instead of every hours element
2. update total for only changed element